# select box change css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Unfortunately I can not work it out with x-editable...

I´m trying to change a (hprimary) css class on select with x-editable. Here is my jsfiddel: [jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/ffvtbyaw/1/) (only with x-editable). Also, i tried It with a normal select button and it is working there. ( [jsfiddel2](http://jsfiddle.net/ss7bzyfy/1/) ) So what do I have to change in x-editable script to make it work?

html:

```
<div class="hpanel hprimary" id="overview">
 </div>
  <div><label class="control-label">TEST</label> 
    <a href="#" id="select" data-type="select" data-pk="1"data-value="" 
       data-title="" class="editable editable-click" style="color: gray;">not selected</a>
  </div>
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
$('#select').editable({
    prepend: "not selected",
    placement: 'right',
    source: [{
        value: 1,
        text: 'NTP(red)'
    }, {
        value: 2,
        text: 'SUCCESS(green)'
    }, {
        value: 3,
        text: 'OPTION(blue)'
    }],

});
});
```

css:

```
.hpanel {
background-color: none;
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
margin-bottom: 25px
}
.hpanel.hprimary .panel-body {
border-top: 2px solid #34495e
}
.hpanel.hgreen .panel-body {
border-top: 2px solid #62cb31
}
.hpanel.hblue .panel-body {
border-top: 2px solid #3498db
}
.hpanel.hred .panel-body {
border-top: 2px solid #e74c3c
}
```

Comment: no one who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `validate()` callback option as described [here](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#gettingstarted) to be alerted when the user has selected a value.

Based on your example, you would then use a regular expression to extract the color from the text value and add the appropriate class to the `hpanel` element.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I just started with Javascript. Can you maybe be more specific? Sorry!

Comment: Add this method to the 'editable' config object after 'source': `validate: function(value) {
   /* logic to set the hpanel class */
}`

Comment: You also needed to add an element with class `panel-body`.  See your updated code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9mgj3tu8/).

Comment: brilliant! thank you so much. I just thought it had to be more complicated!